# White Spacing between images in email template

Tags: html, css, email, templates, spacing

I'm working on an email template but have tried everything I know to get rid of a `2px` gap between my images in my email template from changing the background color of the `<td>` to adding inline styles to get rid of the spacing but nothing seems to work can someone please help. Thank you

```html
<table style="background-color: #EBEBEA;" width="800px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="599" height="66" alt="Logo" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0" /></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566__180.jpg" width="41" height="66" alt="Follow  On Twitter" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0"/></a>
    </td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="28" height="66" alt="Follow  On Facebook" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566__180.jpg" width="27" height="66" alt="Follow  On LinkedIn" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="27" height="66" alt="Follow  On Instagram" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566__180.jpg" width="29" height="66" alt="Follow  On Medium" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="49" height="66" alt="Email A with any questions" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This problem is hard to reproduce and therefor it is hard to assist you on fixing this problem, could you please improve the code provided to a working example of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display: block` to `<a>` tag.
Then move width and height to the attribute `style=""`.

If this does not help the problem may be the size of the images themselves.
For me it looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlN24.png)

I also wanted to point out that you have 2 times the height adjustment in `<img>` tags.
This should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `height: auto;` from `<img>` which used as a inline style.

`height: auto;` is overriding  `height="66"`.

```html
<table style="background-color: #EBEBEA;" width="800px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="599" height="66" alt="Logo" style="width: 100%;  display: block; border: 0" /></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566__180.jpg" width="41" height="66" alt="Follow  On Twitter" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0"/></a>
    </td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="28" height="66" alt="Follow  On Facebook" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566__180.jpg" width="27" height="66" alt="Follow  On LinkedIn" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="27" height="66" alt="Follow  On Instagram" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566__180.jpg" width="29" height="66" alt="Follow  On Medium" style="width: 100%;  display: block; border: 0"/></a></td>

    <td style="padding: 0; line-height: 5px;" align="left"><a href=""><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__180.jpg" width="49" height="66" alt="Email A with any questions" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0"/></a></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```